# Make Linux (ubuntu/centos) bootable HDD without USB, without optical drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, centos

Is it possible, and if so: how, to create a ready-to-use Linux HDD which you simply drop into a rack, and can use normally?

The problem is that we have a server with only a single working SATA bay we need to get running, and no optical drive. The USB ports are disabled on startup, so you can't boot from those.

We've tried Ubuntu and Ubuntu server, but the installers cannot install to the drive they came on. (Ubuntu server doesn't see any other drives, and Ubuntu desktop can't unmount the active drive)

Plus points if it can be done from a windows PC.

Comment: @ser65023 1) Can you add another drive to that server even if it's just dangling off the wires and a "Y" power cable? 2) Are USB ports just blocked at boot, or can you connect a drive to them after boot? 3) Please get the model # off the serial number sticker, for model numbers on front or top are put there by Marketing to look pretty and often differ from the true model # needed to find the right manual. 4) Is another machine available to install Ubuntu on, so the Ubuntu booting drive can move into the drive bay of the target server? Please click [edit] to put info in the question.

Comment: @K7AAY that seems a little excessive to me tbh

Comment: If you can't provide a make and model, well.... bless your heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bare-Metal approach with another Computer

With Linux, it is generally possible to just perform the installation on another computer and then move the HDD to the target server:

1. Add the new HDD to another computer
2. On that computer boot the installer of your Linux distribution and install to the newly added HDD.

Watch out for the following things:

- The boot mode (UEFI / Legacy BIOS) on the server should be the same as on the auxiliary computer used.
- Make sure installation really happens (only) to the correct HDD. Installers tend to automatically write parts of the bootloader to the "first" HDD independent on the installation driver if the user is not careful and overrides this behaviour.

## VM-approach with another Computer

As I do not like to block a whole computer with just performing the installation, my preferred way would be to attach the HDD to another computer and on that computer perform the installation inside a virtual machine that can access (exactly and only) the newly added HDD.

This has the advantage of making installation easier in case the "installation" computer has multiple HDDs and could even work under Windows?

The hint about UEFI/BIOS from before still applies.

## Complex option: Network Boot

At least some installers (no idea about Ubuntu, but for Debian its possible) support installing over network. This allows you to just install on the server so as long as network access is possible.

## Complex option: Install from the HDD onto the HDD.

It is possible to do this, but you need to familiarize yourself with the internals of the booting mechanism of the installation procedure you want to use. The procedure will then often go as follows:

1. Prepare a FAT32 partition holding the installation data on the HDD and make the HDD bootable (syslinux is often used for this). An interesting trick would be to choose the partition size to match the size of a partition that is not part of the initial system installation (data partion, swap partition come to mind)
2. Boot into the installer and create a new partition for OS installation. Install Linux.
3. Boot into the newly installed Linux and reformat the originally used installation partition to be a swap or data partition.

Comment: Top stuff, allmost forgot about the bios thing. We're gonna try option 1 next. We tried the partitioning trick, but ubuntu wanted to remount the entire drive and the installer got stuck in a loop. Maybe buggy or I did something wrong.

Comment: You're welcome :) In case it turns out the last option is to be followed, an approach to consider might also be `toram` boot mode, although it has been ages since I used it, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from